# Unable to access files in custom cocoapods iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I have implemented custom cocoapods in iOS swift but i am unable to access the file that i have developed in my framework. I have installed the framework using pod install and given the local path to that directory and it is even imported successfully. But when I try to access it, it doesn't finds the file. I have attached the images of the code files below. Please help me out, I will be grateful.
[image: Here is the image]

My podspec file is as follows:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name         = "MuneebTestCocoapod"
  spec.version      = "1.0.0"
  spec.summary      = "A short description of MuneebTestCocoapod.podspec."
  spec.description  = "The description comes here"
  spec.homepage     = "http://gitlab.phonecheck.com/muneeb.rehman/muneebtestcocoapod"
  spec.license      = "MIT"
  spec.author             = { "Muneeb ur Rehman" => "muneeb.ur.rehman@upgenicsint.work" }
  spec.platform     = :ios, "11.0"
  spec.source       = { :git => "http://gitlab.phonecheck.com/muneeb.rehman/muneebtestcocoapod.git", :tag => "#{spec.version}" }
  spec.source_files = "MuneebTestCocoapod/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
end
```

Comment: Make your class Public or open. Also, your init is private so you can not create instances of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you check `MyService` class is a by default `internal` access level. While you making `pod` and wants to use outside the module you should need to make your class `public` or `open`.

Also, You can't make an instance of `MyService` class as you added private access specifier to `init`.

So make it public init and public class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Yes I was using wrong access level. @RajaKishan

Comment: if I want to push view controller from a framework, how can I do that?

Comment: Basically I have posted a notification, and my class is listening to it. Now i want to push my view controller from that class

Comment: I think you need to ask separate questions. BTW you can push from TopMostViewController

Comment: but in our framework we can't access the top most view controller from an object class